# Is it possible to have 2 urls for a single Github repository

Tags: github

I was wondering if it's possible to have 2 Github urls that point to the same repository. The reason I want this is I posted a link to a repository somewhere where it is not possible to change my submission. Now I want to put the repository on my resume, but the repository name is so long that it won't fit on one line.  I'd like to have a way to put it on my resume without breaking the original link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no: the GitHub URL is unique.
Your options are:

1. Work with the GitHub URL as-is (span multiple lines).
2. If your résumé supports HTML, use an href.
3. Fork the repository to your account, rename it with a shorter title, and put that in your résumé. Interested readers can click through the "forked from" link.